# AddTrust_External_Root.pem in fedora?

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, ssl

My campus network has switched its wifi network to protected EAP and requires me to provide AddTrust_External_Root.pem as a CA certificate.
On Ubuntu the file is found in /etc/ssl/certs but in my fedora installation that folder is empty.

How can I generate one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who stumble into this issue (like I did), the certificate can be found at `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem` on Fedora. [Source](http://lapserv.maths.cam.ac.uk/docs/ubuntu1110_eduroam_wired.html)